# CakePHP transitive associations in the Blog Post/Comment/User Model

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm teaching myself cakePHP, and I have a question about model associations. I'm adding a commenting system. The problem is in my Posts `view()` action, I can't see the user who made comments, only the FK `user_id` (The display looks like "Comment Title by 1"). A User has many Posts and Comments, a Post belongs to a User and has many Comments, and a comment belongs to both a Post and a User, like so:

**User**

```
public $hasMany = array(
'Post' => array(
  'className' => 'Post',
  'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
  ),
'Comment' => array(
  'className' => 'comment',
  'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
  )
);
```

**Post**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
  'User' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
  )
);
public $hasMany = array(
  'Comment' => array(
     'className' => 'Comment',
     'foreignKey' => 'post_id'
  )
);
```

**Comment**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
  'Post' => array(
    'className' => 'Post',
    'foreignKey' => 'post_id'
  ),
  'User' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
  )
);
```

**PostController**

```
public function view($id = null) {
  //check it's valid, set the options to find the id
  $post = $this->Post->find('first', $options);
  //set the Post model, fire the view
}
```

Then in the view I `foreach` through `$post['Comment']` which works fine, but it doesn't include the full user model, only the user_id key from the `Comment` model, it doesn't chase the transitivity.

I've tried setting the `recursive` param on `find()` all the way up to 2, but that doesn't bring in the `User` Model under the `Comment` model

**Update:** I was looking at the SQL log for my posts/view action and there are 2 distinct queries:

```
SELECT `Post`./*several fields*/, `User`./*several fields*/ FROM `blog`.`posts` AS `Post` LEFT JOIN `blog`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Post`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `Post`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1  1   1   0   

SELECT `Comment`.`id`, `Comment`.`post_id`, `Comment`.`user_id`, `Comment`.`subject`, `Comment`.`body`, `Comment`.`created`, `Comment`.`previous_edit` FROM `blog`.`comments` AS `Comment` WHERE `Comment`.`post_id` = (1)
```

So the first query is for the post and it does the join to pick up the belongsTo relationship. But when it writes the comments query it just filters on the post_id without joining on the users table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. I had to use the `finderQuery` property of the [hasMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany) relationship. So the code looks like this:

```
public $hasMany = array(
'Comment' => array(
  'className' => 'Comment',
  'finderQuery' => 'SELECT `Comment`./*several fields*/, `User`.`username` 
     FROM `blog`.`comments` AS `Comment` LEFT JOIN `blog`.`users` AS `User` ON
     (`Comment`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `Comment`.`post_id` = {$__cakeID__$}'
)
```

);

`{$__cakeID__$}` is some cake magic that represents the id of the object you are working on, in this case the blog post.